# ColdFusion HTML form error Element element_name is undefined in FORM even though form. scope is added in tag

Tags: javascript, html, forms, coldfusion

I've have following `.cfm` file. That is called on a Submit button click from another `.cfm` file. But submit button click gives the error: `Element TYPE_QUERY is undefined in FORM. error occurred in line 3`. As you can see I'm adding the `.form` scope in the tag:

```
<cfset sdate = Form.s_date>
<cfset edate = Form.e_date>
<cfset type_query = Form.type_query>
<cfif type_query eq "query1">
    <cflocation url="query1.cfm?fdate=#sdate#&edate=#edate#">
<cfelseif type_query eq "query2">
    <cflocation url="query2.cfm?sdate=#sdate#&edate=#edate#">
    <cflocation url="report_test.cfm">
</cfif>
```

Comment: Do a `<cfdump var="#form#">` and see if that variable is even being pushed over. Also make sure you are doing a `post` and not a `get`

Comment: And please validate user inputs, e.g. use `structKeyExists(Form, "type_query")` to check if the field was provided.

Comment: If the input for query_type in your form is either a series of checkboxes or radio buttons, and nothing is selected, that form field will not exist when you post the form.  That might not be what happened in this case, but then again, it might.  @JamesAMohler, he has to be doing a `post`.  If he was doing a `get`, the error would have occurred two lines earlier.

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

1. You don't need to define new variables based on form scoped variables, just reference the form scoped variables.
2. Verify that `form.type_query` exists as Alex suggests. (Did you have a form field named `type_query`?)
3. Throw an error if it doesn't.
4. Make sure that you contextually encode user input to protect against Cross-Site Scripting attacks (`encodeForURL()` in this case.)
5. You can only call one `cflocation` at a time, you'll never redirect to `report_test.cfm`.
6. If `type_query` matches neither "query1" or "query2", throw an error or redirect to another page.
7. Optional: Set a default value for `type_query`.

```
<--- Optional (7):
<cfparam name="form.type_query" type="string" default="query1">
--->

<cfif structKeyExists(form, "type_query")>

    <cfif compareNoCase(form.type_query, "query1") EQ 0>
        <cflocation url="query1.cfm?fdate=#encodeForURL(form.s_date)#&edate=#encodeForURL(form.e_date)#">
    <cfelseif compareNoCase(form.type_query, "query2") EQ 0>
        <cflocation url="query2.cfm?sdate=#encodeForURL(s_date)#&edate=#encodeForURL(e_date)#">
    <cfelse>
        <cfthrow type="Application" message="Invalid value for the form variable 'type_query'.">
    </cfif>

<cfelse>

    <cfthrow type="Application" message="The variable 'type_query' was not part of the form data.">

</cfif>
```

Comment: Throwing an error if the form field doesn't exist seems like an unnecessary expenditure of time and effort.  He's already getting that.